# " segmentation fault " in fortran

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I have questions :
Is it possible to define final-value of do loop(ngal) as a free parameter with out exact value or not when I don't know the exact size of my catalog either I don't know the size of nm and nz? ( the whole code as you wished )

```
integer i,iz,im,ngal,n_thresh,nmax,nz,nm,ok,total,ii,j
integer, dimension(:,:),allocatable :: ngalb
double precision ramin,ramax,decmin,decmax,zmin,zmax,mag_min,mag_max,step,bin,S,dix,fi,Vmax,zbin,magbin
double precision, dimension (:),allocatable :: ra,dec,mag_g,mag_r,mag_i,redshift,zup
double precision, dimension (:,:,:),allocatable :: magb,zb
character plotname*100,zbin_str*4

open(unit=1,file='Lagos12.i.asc')
open(2,file='bin.asc')
open(3,file='mag_vol.asc')
open(4,file='luminosity_func.asc')



ramin=0.0
ramax=2.0
decmin=-2.0
    decmax=2.0
zmin=0.0
zmax=3.2
mag_min=13
mag_max=26
step=0.1
bin=0.5
n_thresh=20

 allocate (ra(ngal),stat=ok)
 allocate (dec(ngal),stat=ok)
 allocate (mag_g(ngal),stat=ok)
 allocate (mag_r(ngal),stat=ok)
 allocate (mag_i(ngal),stat=ok)
 allocate (redshift(ngal),stat=ok)
 allocate(ngalb(nz,nm),stat=ok)




     ngalb=0

     do i=1,ngal
     read(1,*)  ra(i),dec(i),mag_g(i),mag_r(i),mag_i(i),redshift(i)

     iz=int((redshift(i)-zmin)/step)+1
     im=int((mag_i(i)-mag_min)/bin)+1
     ngalb(iz,im)=ngalb(iz,im)+1
     enddo

 nmax=0
     do iz=1,nz
        do im=1,nm
           nmax=max(nmax,ngalb(iz,im))
        enddo
     enddo


     allocate(magb(nz,nm,nmax),stat=ok)
     allocate(zb(nz,nm,nmax),stat=ok)
   allocate(zup(nz),stat=ok)


     ngalb=0

     do i=1,ngal

     read(1,*)ra(i),dec(i),mag_g(i),mag_r(i),mag_i(i),redshift(i)

     iz=int((redshift(i)-zmin)/step)+1
     im=int((mag_i(i)-mag_min)/bin)+1


    ngalb(iz,im)=ngalb(iz,im)+1
     j=ngalb(iz,im)
     magb(iz,im,j)=mag_i(i)
     zb(iz,im,j)=redshift(i)
 write(2,'(2x,3i5,2x,i5,2x,f10.7,2x,f10.5)')iz,im,j,ngalb(im,iz),magb(im,iz,j),zb(im,iz,j)
     enddo





deallocate(magb,zb)
deallocate(ngalb)
deallocate (ra,dec,mag_g,mag_r,mag_i,redshift,zup)
```

Comment: can you post a complete code including declarations?

Comment: the question is in itself not understandable, but from the code I would assume OP's problem is that the size of most arrays should equal the number of lines read (unknown when allocatin), and the size of `ngalb` depends on the shifts in the data (also unkown when allocating). So, the solution is to think a little bit.

Comment: @steabert: I agree. I see two possibilities to do that: Use fixed-size arrays and fill them until there are no more datasets in the file (using `iostat` or `end`), or reading in the file first using dummy-arguments to determine the number of lines (records?), then doing the allocations and finally read in the file for real.

Comment: Or even reallocate the arrays, when they are full and continue reading. But for a beginner I would choose 1 pass for number of lines, `rewind` and read the lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To sum up the comments by High Performance Mark, steabert, Vladimir F, and myself:

```
! First pass: Determine sizes
nm = 0 ; nz = 0 ; ngal = 0
do
  read(1,*,iostat=ierr)  dummy_ra, dummy_dec, dummy_mag_g, dummy_mag_r, &
                         dummy_mag_i, dummy_redshift
  if ( ierr < 0 ) exit ! End of file
  if ( ierr > 0 ) stop 'An error occured reading from unit 1'
  nz = max(nz,int((dummy_redshift-zmin)/step)+1)
  nm = max(nm,int((dummy_mag_i-mag_min)/bin)+1)
  ngal = ngal + 1
enddo

! Allocate arrays
allocate (ra(ngal), dec(ngal), mag_g(ngal), mag_r(ngal), mag_i(ngal), &
          redshift(ngal), ngalb(nm,nz), stat=ierr) 
if ( ierr /= 0 ) stop 'Cannot allocate memory'
ngalb=0

! Second pass: Read in
rewind(1)
do i=1,ngal
  read(1,*) ra(i), dec(i), mag_g(i), mag_r(i), mag_i(i), redshift(i)
  iz = int((redshift(i)-zmin)/step)+1
  im = int((mag_i(i)-mag_min)/bin)+1
  ngalb(im,iz) = ngalb(im,iz)+1
enddo
```